# what is Backup file location

Tags: 2010, backup, restore

I want to configure default backup and restore settings. I don't know what backup location should I use? I use this location: `\\myserver\myfolder` is that correct?
I got following error:

> Directory `\\myserver\myfolder` does not exist or the SQL Server service account and the `SPDEV\mustafa.noor` service account do not have permission to read or write to the backup folder. Specify a different directory or ensure that the SharePoint Timer service and Microsoft SQL Server service accounts have Full Control permission on both the file share and the underlying folder.

What location should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the service account do not have permission to read or write to the backup folder

It seems like you have limited access, or no access to the backup folder. Give yourself access, or the service account you're executing the backup with read/write access to that particular folder - and you should be able to perform backup.

More to read on backup: [Back up a farm (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428295%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: How i give access to myself ? I am already member of Farm Administrators Group. Second question: The backup folder will be created automatically (myfolder) or should i create myself Before performing backup?

Comment: You may be Farm Admin without being an administrator on the actual SQL server. Log in with the server administrator account to give other accounts access to folders. Create the backup folder first, give access right secondly and third - start backup!